# How to Configure Remote Hbase Server to my Java Application

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am very New to Hadoop and Hbase, Hbase is completely Different From RDMS.
I want to create a table and load it in Hbase using MapReduce. Hadoop and Hbase are in different server. I have access to that server using 'Putty' using IP address, username and password. In JDBC, we can configure using driver, username & password, but in HBase how I can configure IP address, username & password to my application which is in my machine. I checked with 'hbase-site.xml'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When connecting to a remote system you cn use this code for configuration 

`config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", args[0]);// ip of hbase server(remote)
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", args[1]);// portno : 2181 default`

Edit the conf/regionservers file in hbase directory to add the Hbase server (Remote) in it 
(I did this and didnt need to edit the etc/hosts to get a hbase server in my office network)
i.e. after editing regionservers will look like

localhost
ip address of the remote hbase server

eg
localhost
10.132.258.366

Answer (score 5):

You can connect to remote HBase using  object. Using that class you can set all necessary arguments in an xml file like hbase-site.xml and pass the file name to Configuration object using addResource method
example:

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration hbaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
hbaseConfiguration.addResource(new Path("/home/john/hbase-site.xml));
```